Share Android Studio SDKs and projects between users in Mac
I have two users on the Mac
with User1 I have installed everything needed for Android Studio and my projects but in User2 when I want to open Android Studio it asks to download the SDKs.
I can't download them all again because my Mac has no room left.
how can I share these files?

By default Android Studio will want the Android SDK to be in $HOME/Library/Android/sdk.  This can be changed to whatever you like, for example /Users/Shared/Library/Android/sdk from within Android Studio:

Note that this will need doing for both users and you may need to massage the file permissions to allow both users to update the SDK from within Android Studio.
